# Why does latlng from an address result in no arguments found error?

Tags: android

Here is the function I am calling where I pass in a street address to obtain the lat/lon so that I can use it on google maps.

```
  public LatLng getLocation(String locationName) {

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
    LatLng end;

    try {
        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName, 1);
        Address add = addressList.get(0);
        double lat = add.getLatitude();
        double lon = add.getLongitude();
        end = new LatLng(lat, lon);

    }
    catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
    return end;
}
```

And this is the error:

> error: constructor LatLng in class LatLng cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: no arguments
>   found: double,double
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Any idea what could could possibly be causing this error?

Comment: Try using the latest version of Android, clean and rebuild.

Comment: I am on the latest version of Android. Cleaned but cannot rebuild because of that error.